# Ubuntu Server 16.04 Keyboard configuration ignored even if it seems correct

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm "fighting" with a keyboard related issue on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

My /etc/default/keyboard contains:
*XKBMODEL="pc105"

XKBLAYOUT="it"

XKBVARIANT=""

XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess*"

My /etc/default/locale contains:
*LANG="it_IT.UTF-8"*

**But ubuntu recognize my keyboard as an US layout, while I'm using an Italian one.**

The "locale" output is:
*LANG=it_IT.UTF-8

LANGUAGE=

LC_CTYPE="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_NUMERIC="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_TIME="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_COLLATE="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_MONETARY="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_MESSAGES="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_PAPER="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_NAME="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_ADDRESS="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_TELEPHONE="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_MEASUREMENT="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_IDENTIFICATION="it_IT.UTF-8"

LC_ALL=*

How I can solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no relationship whatsoever between the `/etc/default/keyboard` (which tells the system what characters are produced by what keys) and `/etc/default/locale` (which tells the system in what language to display messages and how you would like your numbers and dates to be formatted). They serve different purposes. Have you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`? (Don't forget to `sudo systemctl restart keyboard-setup` afterwards.) Since the machine is a server, you must also understand that this configuration refers only to a physical keyboard connected to the computer.

Comment: Thank you @AlexP, yes I ran several times sudo `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and restarted the service. I'm using a physical keyboard. It seems that all is ignored and go to default US layout.

Comment: Do you have a file `~/.keyboard`?

Comment: No, there isn't...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on 18.04 -- the system obeys `/etc/default/keyboard`. I no longer have a machine with 16.04.